# Accessing the file which is already in OPEN mode by some other process

Tags: file, sed

I am currently in a situation where a certain FILE_HANDLE is in OPEN mode and I need to copy and process the file contents using following command-

```
sed 's/\t/;/g' SOURCEFILE > TARGETFILE
```

SOURCEFILE filehandle is in OPEN mode by some other process, Can the above command execute successfully regardless the file is already OPEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, read access to a file can be shared across processes. Each process maintains it's own file seek position.

However, if one process is writing to a file while another process is reading it, it will lead to unpredictable results.